# write the expression for $J (x, y)$

Tags: linear-algebra

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{cc|c}
  2&-3\\
  2&-4
\end{array}
\right] $$

Given the matrix P above, and a column vector $\mathbf x=(x,y)^T$, write the expression for $J(\mathbf x,\mathbf y)=\mathbf x^T(P^TP)\mathbf x$.

I am confused by what writing the "expression" out means exactly. Can someone elaborate via example or a similar problem as to what the question is asking for?

Comment: @Parcly why would you change the post to something apparently unrelated to the original question asked?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom It was already changed...

Comment: For example: if $\mathbf x = (x,y)^T$, then we could "write the expression" for $(1,2)\  \mathbf x$ as $1\cdot x + 2 \cdot y = x + 2y$.

Comment: Essentially you  are asked to write the expression as a polynomial in $x,y$

Comment: Do you mind elaborating just a little bit? Assuming that J(x,y)=x*P, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:
$$
J(x,y)=[x,y]
\begin{bmatrix}2&2\\-3&-4 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}2&-3\\2&-4 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x\\y \end{bmatrix}
$$

can you write a polynomial from this?

Comment: Is it $$8x^2-28y+25y^2$$?

Comment: Yes!  It is easy ! :)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Careful! it is  $-28 xy$ ...